# How to customize django form validation

Tags: python, django

I‘m a newer in python，django

model：

```
class Product(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    warehouse = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    class Meat:
        unique_together = (('name', 'warehouse'),)
```

When i submit the form

if the name input field is empty，then I got the message : **the field is......**

if the name field value and the warehouse field value is equal, then I got the message: **...is exist**

How can I customize the validation error message(the stronger text)?

Comment: FYI: Usually its a good idea to post the whole error message, not just a snippet.

Comment: e..My error message is Chinese, so I just use a snippet here.I just want to know how to change the error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override error messages in the form:

```
name = forms.CharField(error_messages={
    'min_length': _('Enter a longer name'),
})

warehouse = forms.CharField(error_messages={
    'invalid': _('Enter a unique combination'),
})
```

Take a look at the django forms source to see the different error messages you can over ride.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py